# "Told somebody did something" VS "Helped someone do something"

Tags: grammar

[Failing](http://lovefreenovels.com/Fiction/This_Is_Falling/page_48.html)

In the same article, there are 2 different "did ... do" styles.

> I **told** my parents I **didn’t** want to come home for fall break,
>
> ...
>
> I **helped** my dad **pick** out a few dates that coincided with
>   Nate’s second fall tournament.

The first is "did ... did", and the second is "did ... do." Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why? Because that is the tense of the clause.

> I told my parents I didn’t want to come home.

You *told* them in the past, and your thought of not wanting to come home also occurred in the past.

You could easily say:

> I *told* my parents that *I am not* coming home.

This is talking about your telling them in the past about a future action. Although the information conveyed is essentially the same, the difference is you are here referring to the action whereas in your original example you are referring to the point at which you *decided* on this action.